# The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized without AppMeasurement

Tags: ios, admob, cocoapods

I'm not very experienced in the IOS development. This is my first try to implement Google AdMob to my application, and I get this error when I try to run the simulator:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GADInvalidInitializationException', reason: 'The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized without AppMeasurement. Google AdMob publishers, follow instructions here: https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-ios-update-plist to include the AppMeasurement framework and set the -ObjC linker flag.

I'm using Xcode 12 beta on macOS Big Sur. I tried to reinstall Google pod a couple of times, but still get the same error. Please help

Comment: I've been having the same issue after updating AdMob SDK using Cocoapods. I kept my cocoapods install, but still did step 2 of https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#manual_download. Now it works, but I don't get why the documentation states that cocoapods should be enough

Comment: Did you put the SDK framework files to your project or just added the -ObjC to Other Linker Flags?

Comment: I just added the flag. The frameworks were already installed via Cocoapods, but somehow the cocoapods config for AdMob didn't update the main project configuration to add this flag

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Manually add the `-ObjC` linker flag to **Other Linker Flags** in your target's build settings even if you're using CocoaPods or Swift Package Manager.

[image: Manually adding the -Obj` linker flag to Other Linker Flags]

Comment: It may be better to just add `-ObjC` at the target level and inherit others from xcconfig file:
`$(inherited) -ObjC`

Comment: @gonsee not sure what you mean. This is the target level. Did you mean the project?

Comment: In my case I had the flag on my target but it didn't work until I added it at the project level, then it worked!

Comment: Also do this if you are importing it via Swift Package Manager, won't work otherwise!

Comment: thank you so much save me more than four times :)

Answer (score 45):

Try to add this property in your Info.plist file
[image]

It works for me

Comment: it works with iOS 15+ thank you man.

Comment: Also works for me on IOS 16. Thank you

Comment: worked for me too , swiftUI, xcode 14.1, swift5, ios 16

Comment: works for me too, UIKIt, Xcode 14, swift 5 ios 16

Comment: Also worked on iOS 17+.

Answer (score 8):

[image: UI of Xcode Version 14 >=]

For anyone who has encountered this problem recently, this is the UI for Xcode version 14 or newer. You must set the `-ObjC` flag for both the "Debug" and "Release" configurations.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who using Swift Package Manager, go to your target and change the version rule from main to the next major (enter the latest version - 9.0.0 at the moment) and it should work:

[image]

Comment: My app kept crashing upon start. saying that adunit was nil. this was fix

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add `-ObjC` flag in Other Linker Flags for both Debug and Release.
[image: Linker flag settings]

Comment: thanks for the hint. Solved the issue for me unter iOS 17.0.1