# Ads SDK was initialized without AppMeasurement

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I know they have updated the sdk, so I have made changes and I am pretty sure that all my code for ads is as it is in the new ads sdk documentation. I have also provided the new `ads tracking usage`. `App id` is also provided in the info.plist. So I dont know why I am constantly facing this issue when I run my app.

The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized without AppMeasurement. Google AdMob publishers, follow instructions here: https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-ios-update-plist to include the AppMeasurement framework and set the -ObjC linker flag. Google Ad Manager publishers, follow instructions here: https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-ios-update-plist

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized without AppMeasurement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66411662/2108547)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Need to add the following value to info.plist

```
<key>GADIsAdManagerApp</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: It worked for me, even if I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

For me manually adding the `-ObjC` linker flag to the build settings fixed it (`OTHER_LDFLAGS`).

Answer (score 0):

So, I have found a temporary solution unless someone finds a permanent one. 
If anyone else face this issue, you need to decrease the Admob sdk version in `Podfile` to be maximum `7.67`, `7.68` and higher are facing the same issue.
**`pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '7.67.0'`**

Comment: I also saw, after installing SDK 7.67.0, it added the -ObjC to $(inherited). Maybe that's what fixed the problem. Anyway, it did work.